# JAWS does not read aria-label for link within a link inside li with role="tab"

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

The below is my code for aria accessibility in html.It's working fine with ChromeVox but when running with JAWS all the aria-labels are read when focus is on link `Menu1`.But aria-label of link `options` should be read when focus goes on it.

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #div1{
        padding : 12px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="tab">
            <div id="div1">
                <a tabindex="0" aria-label="first menuitem" class="active">Menu1
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-label="Press spacebar to use options menu" tabindex="0">options</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li role="presentation"><a tabindex="0" role="menuitem">Properties</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a tabindex="0" role="menuitem">Edit Properties</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li role="tab">
            <a href="#">Menu2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

What I want is the aria-label of each link should be read only when the focus goes on particular link, not when the focus is on link `Menu1`, which is the current behaviour.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do not nest interactive controls, such as `<a href>`. Fix that first (and get rid of the `tabindex`). https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#interactive-content

Comment: Oh wait — did you intentionally exclude the `href`? If so, I will have to amend my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue at play here is that you have a link within a link. Not only is it [invalid to nest an `<a href>`](https://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element) within an `<a href>` (or any [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#interactive-content)), but that also means screen readers may do unexpected things when they encounter nested interactive controls. Things which cannot be considered wrong.

This means you cannot convert the second link to a `<button>` and expect things to be ok as you will still have nested interactive controls.

A second issue that will come into play later is any instructions to use specific keys unless those keys are mapped. For example, your instructional text says to "Press spacebar to use options menu" but that menu appears to be in a link. The space bar does not activate a link when it has focus, it will scroll the page.

The [WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1 for a tab control](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#tabpanel) details the keyboard controls that it will need to support.

Finally, since `<a href>` is already interactive content and is keyboard accessible, you do not need `tabindex="0"` at all. You can (and should, IMO) remove it.

Comment: Thnks for your answer.I have updated my code. Hope you will get clear idea of what I actually want.As you have said I can't use link within a link. Can you plz help me to change my code?

Comment: I see that you want tabs. Tabs have been written over and over and there are lots of examples out there. Accessible examples are ideal, of course. Here is one with very simple HTML that you can use as a base: http://heydonworks.com/practical_aria_examples/#tab-interface If you are trying to do a drop-down menu in your tabs, I suggest you do not.

Comment: One thing I want to mention here is that, if I remove `role="tab"` from `li` JAWS will read as focus goes on the link.So is there any way to fulfill my requirement by keeping `role` in `li`?

Comment: You mean JAWS will announce the list item? That should have no bearing on the link. There are so many things happening in this code that I think you have to address the nesting first, then address the structure, and then you can start to layer roles into it one feature at a time. Also, recommend against any `menu` and `menuitem` roles unless you are trying to recreate an OS-level menu.

Answer (score 0):

Do not nest any interactive elements. If when you click on those anchor tags it redirects the user to another page than they should have a href attribute. I am assuming you are handling the redirection with some sort of click event, if that is the case, try adding

```
href="#"
```

Do not use tabindexes unless extremely necessary, adding the href attribute should be sufficient to add those links to the tab order.

I have no idea how your design looks like, but I would suggest the following approach

```
<ul role="tablist">
    <li role="tab">
        <a href="#" aria-label="first menuitem">Menu1</a>
        <div id="submenu" aria-hidden="true" style="display:none">
            <a href="#" aria-label="Press spacebar to use options menu">options</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I added `aria-hidden="true" style="display:none"` because I am assuming you are going to add some kind of mouse-over and focus event on the menu tab that will then show the `submenu div`.

Comment: I have tried as per your suggestion. But It doesn't work. Can you help me with updated code?